# How to extend Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get Laravel database table's indexes.

I know I can get them as below

```
\DB::select("SHOW INDEX FROM $db_table_name WHERE non_unique = 1 AND column_name = '$db_column_name'");
```

But I think it's not good way.
I want to get them like:

```
// this
\DB::getIndex($db_table_name, $db_column_name);

// Or this
\DB::table($db_table_name)->getIndex($db_column_name);
```

I think I have to extend query builder.
Please tell me how to do.

Edit--
I use
Laravel Framework 5.6.39
PHP 7.2.17

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forget. I use Laravel Framework 5.6.39.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you will need to extend the query builder, so you can place this code in your `AppServiceProvider` `boot` method, or if you have a custom service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder; // at the top of the class

Builder::macro('getIndex', function($columnName){
   return $this->getConnection()
           ->select("show index from {$this->from} where non_unique = 1 and column_name='$columnName'");
});
```

Then to use it:

```
DB::table('TABLE_NAME')->getIndex('COLUMN_NAME');
```

Hope it helps.